# Unable to add image in datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid, timepicker

I am using `.timepicker` inside `.jqGrid` with `filterToolbar`. I want to add an image next to filter bar where the user should see a time when they click an image.

If I just use `$(element).timepicker();` then I see the time when I click on filter bar but When I do following, `timepicker` is not working at all.

```
$(element).timepicker({
                showOn: "button",
                buttonImage: "https://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/datepicker/images/calendar.gif",
                buttonImageOnly: true,
          });
```

The same options work with `datepicker`. What am I missing here? Is this due to `jquery.timepicker.js` version?

**Working Demo**

```js
$(function() {
  "use strict";

  $("#grid").jqGrid({
    colModel: [{
      name: "StartRunTime",
      label: "Start Run Time",
      align: "center",
      sorttype: "time",
      formatter: "time",
      searchoptions: {
        dataInit: function(element) {
          $(element).timepicker();
        }
      }
    }],
    data: [{
      StartRunTime: "12:00"
    }],
   
    caption: ".jqGrid Test"
  }).jqGrid('filterToolbar', {
    autoSearch: true
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/free-jqgrid/4.14.1/jquery.jqgrid.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-timepicker/1.8.9/jquery.timepicker.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/free-jqgrid/4.14.1/css/ui.jqgrid.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-timepicker/1.8.9/jquery.timepicker.css">

<table id="grid"></table>
```

**Not Working Demo**

```js
$(function() {
  "use strict";

  $("#grid").jqGrid({
    colModel: [{
      name: "StartRunTime",
      label: "Start Run Time",
      align: "center",
      sorttype: "time",
      formatter: "time",
      searchoptions: {
        dataInit: function(element) {
          $(element).timepicker({
             showOn: "button",
            buttonImage: "https://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/datepicker/images/calendar.gif",
             buttonImageOnly: true,
          });
        }
      }
    }],
    data: [{
      StartRunTime: "12:00"
    }],
   
    caption: ".jqGrid Test"
  }).jqGrid('filterToolbar', {
    autoSearch: true
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/free-jqgrid/4.14.1/jquery.jqgrid.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-timepicker/1.8.9/jquery.timepicker.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/free-jqgrid/4.14.1/css/ui.jqgrid.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-timepicker/1.8.9/jquery.timepicker.css">

<table id="grid"></table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

thats not valid option, but you can insert image and listener like this

```
$(document).on("click", ".showCalendar", function(){
  $("#gs_grid_StartRunTime").timepicker('show');
});
$('#gs_grid_StartRunTime').parent()
  .after('<td><img class="showCalendar" src="https://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/datepicker/images/calendar.gif"></td>');
```

Demo:

```js
$(function() {
  "use strict";

  $("#grid").jqGrid({
    colModel: [{
      name: "StartRunTime",
      label: "Start Run Time",
      align: "center",
      sorttype: "time",
      formatter: "time",
      searchoptions: {
        dataInit: function(element) {
          $(element).timepicker();
        }
      }
    },
    {
     label: "Concept Name",
     name: "ConceptName",
     key: true,
     width: 100,
     align: "center"
    }],
    data: [{
      StartRunTime: "12:00",
      ConceptName: "ABC"
    }],

    caption: ".jqGrid Test"
  }).jqGrid('filterToolbar', {
    autoSearch: true
  });
  $(document).on("click", ".showCalendar", function(){
   $("#gs_grid_StartRunTime").timepicker('show');
  });
  $('#gs_grid_StartRunTime').parent().after('<td><img class="showCalendar" src="https://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/datepicker/images/calendar.gif"></td>');
  
});
```

```css
.showCalendar {
 margin: 0px 2px;
 cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/free-jqgrid/4.14.1/jquery.jqgrid.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-timepicker/1.8.9/jquery.timepicker.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/free-jqgrid/4.14.1/css/ui.jqgrid.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-timepicker/1.8.9/jquery.timepicker.css">

<table id="grid"></table>
```

Comment: This makes sense but it adds an image to all columns if I add any. Here is the link, [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gunjan_prmr/kkxa62wb/). From given example, how can I just add it to `StartRunTime` column?